# How to take the precedence value from multiple table in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables with similar columns which can take different values. IF NULL found for the table in first precedence it checks the second precedence table and if still null, it checks the third table in precedence. Say the joining is on ID which is unique for all tables.

TABLE 1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | NULL |
| NULL | MNO |

TABLE 2:

| Column A1 | Column B1 |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | ABC |
| NULL | NULL |

TABLE 3:

| Column A2 | Column B2 |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | MNO |
| NULL | NULL |

PRECEDENCE TABLE:

|  | FIRST | SECOND | THIRD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COLUMN A | TABLE3 | TABLE1 | TABLE2 |
| COLUMN B | TABLE2 | TABLE1 | TABLE3 |

OUTPUT:

| Column AO | Column BO |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | ABC |
| NULL | MNO |

As part of the solution I am creating the above Precedence table which is a static table storing the precedence values. Now idea is to run an explicit cursor to take the values for each column after joining the three tables. Use a COALEASE function to test the null value. Can it be done this way?

Comment: In SQL (not just Oracle), result sets are unordered (unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause). Since you have no column that specifies an order for your tables then your result sets will be unordered so your precedence table can be read in any order (and similarly for the rows in the other tables).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (in a form we can copy/paste and execute); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with your solution

Comment: “the joining is on ID which is unique for all tables” seems contradictory. If you mean that there is a common ID and all three tables have a row for every ID then it would help if you said that and showed it in your example data. Why do you need the precedence table - are those going to change such that you can’t just hard-code those rules directly in a coalesce? Having that look-up makes things much more complicated and potentially less efficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the same IDs in all three tables you could join the tables with each other on ID and with precedence table on 1=1. Use Case expression and  Coalesce(), aggregation and group by to get output that you ask for:

```sql
WITH  --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl_1 (ID, COL_A, COL_B) AS
        ( Select 1, 'ABC', Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, Null, 'MNO' From Dual 
        ), 
    tbl_2 (ID, COL_A1, COL_B1) AS
        ( Select 1, Null, 'ABC' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, Null, Null From Dual 
        ), 
    tbl_3 (ID, COL_A2, COL_B2) AS
        ( Select 1, 'XYZ', 'MNO' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, Null, Null From Dual 
        ), 
    precedence (COL_X, FST, SCND, THRD) AS
        ( Select 'COLUMN A', 'TBL_3', 'TBL_1', 'TBL_2' From Dual Union All
          Select 'COLUMN B', 'TBL_2', 'TBL_1', 'TBL_3' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    S Q L :
Select 
  Max(
    CASE WHEN p.COL_X = 'COLUMN A' THEN
      Coalesce (Case  When p.FST = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_A 
                      When p.FST = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_A1
                      When p.FST = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_A2
                End,
                Case  When p.SCND = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_A 
                      When p.SCND = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_A1
                      When p.SCND = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_A2
                End,
                Case  When p.THRD = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_A 
                      When p.THRD = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_A1
                      When p.THRD = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_A2
                End
               ) 
    END) "COLUMN_AO",
  Max(
    CASE WHEN p.COL_X = 'COLUMN B' THEN
      Coalesce (Case  When p.FST = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_B 
                      When p.FST = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_B1
                      When p.FST = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_B2
                End,
                Case  When p.SCND = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_B 
                      When p.SCND = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_B1
                      When p.SCND = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_B2
                End,
                Case  When p.THRD = 'TBL_1' Then t1.COL_B 
                      When p.THRD = 'TBL_2' Then t2.COL_B1
                      When p.THRD = 'TBL_3' Then t3.COL_B2
                End
               ) 
    END) "COLUMN_BO"
From        tbl_1 t1 
Left Join   tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.ID = t1.ID)
Left Join   tbl_3 t3 ON(t3.ID = t1.ID)
Left Join   precedence p ON(1 = 1)
Group By t1.ID
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
COLUMN_AO COLUMN_BO
--------- ---------
XYZ       ABC
          MNO       */
```